# Change CAF (Core Audio Format) volume without resampling

Tags: macos, conversion, audio, resampling

I've converted some MP3 files to CAF, but unfortunately all of them have inadecuate volume intensity

Is there a tool to change their volume without resampling, to avoid any possible loss in quality

I used  the following command line to do the conversion on a Mac with XCode installed

```
afconvert -d LEI16 -f 'caff' input_file.mp3 output_file.caf
```